# How do I run phpunit command in Windows command line no matter what directory I am in?

Tags: php, windows, command-line, phpunit

all examples of phpunit I saw run the simple command line tool:

phpunit TestClass

but when I try the same on a directory other than the xampp php dir, I end up getting an "unknown command..."

Is there a way to execute the phpunit command from any directory in the Windows command line?

Comment: that saved me a lot of time :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the phpunit to your System PATH

> Setting Path on Windows Start ->
>   Control Panel -> System -> Advanced
>   Click on Environment Variables, under
>   System Variables, find PATH, and click
>   on it. In the Edit windows, modify
>   PATH by adding the location of the
>   class to the value for PATH. If you do
>   not have the item PATH, you may select
>   to add a new variable and add PATH as
>   the name and the location of the class
>   as the value. Close the window. Reopen
>   Command prompt window, and run phpunit TestClass

Comment: straight to the point...an alternative way would be: right click My Computer, click on Properties, click on Advanced, click Environment Variables, modify the Path env. variable and add the directory (in my case C:\xampp\php ...thanks a lot!